# google Oauth 2 code required in php for displaying game scores from leaderboard

Tags: php, curl, google-play

I have written the CURL code for displaying game scores from a leaderboard but shows an error.

---

```
Array
```

Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [domain] => global
                            [reason] => required
                            [message] => Login Required
                            [locationType] => header
                            [location] => Authorization
                        )

```
            )

        [code] => 401
        [message] => Login Required
    )
```

---

I cannot implement the Oauth2 code with this .....my curl code is below. Please help.

CODE:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("curl_get")) {`enter code here`
function curl_get($kix) {
$header = array( 'Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data', 'Expect:' );
$agent = "Best Runs API/PHP (App ..............)";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $kix);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://...../');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $html;
}
}
$html = @curl_get("https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/leaderboards/leadeboardID");
$json = json_decode($html,true); 
echo $json;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($json);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Google PHP Api Library in your project. https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: i already have this link....but am unable to implement the auth 2 code with my rest of curl code. Please guide.